# Error in Maven building

Tags: maven, clojure

I'm new in Maven

this errors appeared when Maven building

> ```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".   
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
> See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
> details. [INFO] Scanning for projects
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> [INFO] Total time: 4.973s [INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 19 08:17:30 EET 2014 
> [INFO] Final Memory: 3M/7M
> [INFO][ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify
> a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal>
> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.
> Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize,
> generate-sources
> ```

any help ?

here's my pom.xml

```
<pre>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>storm.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>storm-starter</name>
        <url>https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter</url>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>github-releases</id>
                <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>clojars.org</id>
                <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.8.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
                <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.0M8</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>storm</groupId>
                <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0.1</version> <!-- keep storm out of the jar-with-dependencies -->
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>15.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>

            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <sourceDirectory>src/jvm</sourceDirectory>
            <testSourceDirectory>test/jvm</testSourceDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/multilang</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>

            <plugins> <!-- Bind the maven-assembly-plugin to the package phase this will create 
                    a jar file without the storm dependencies suitable for deployment to a cluster. -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass></mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
                    <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.12</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectories>
                            <sourceDirectory>src/clj</sourceDirectory>
                        </sourceDirectories>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>java</executable>
                        <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                        <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                        <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                        <mainClass>${storm.topology}</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
</pre>
```

Comment: can you share your `pom.xml` and the command line you're running?

Comment: i run it using IDE eclipse . Run AS..>Maven Build.I'll add pom.xml now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Run as->Maven Build then you have to specify a specific goal like `install` or `package`  to the Goals field in the dialog box and run.

If it doesn't solve your problem, try running it in the command line once giving `mvn clean install` command and see the results.

More [here](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=/search?q=No%2bgoals%2bhave%2bbeen%2bspecified%2bfor%2bthis%2bbuild.&biw=1280&bih=662&rurl=translate.google.co.in&sl=zh-CN&u=https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException&usg=ALkJrhiFMtLieRPvmXjOXIrYCQmQg9HyXQ)

Comment: what's about the first three lines of my post ?and is goal should make me choose install or package or I'll write it ? cause when i pressed goal and select i didn't found anything to choose it and i got this error [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_38/../lib/tools.jar Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required)

Comment: @user3188912 : What first three lines, I didnot get you. And about the goal , It will open a dialogue box asking for goal , you have enter install / package and run it, If it is not showing it, then go to run configuration and add the goal.

Comment: i mean this SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".   
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further

Comment: @user3188912 That is about the logger configuration, ie slf4j is not configured correctly, which is not related to maven build

Comment: i solved it thanks Allah . the problem is in tools.jar i added external jar and added it manually

Comment: Thanks .but after build success . why pom.xml file have a question mark on it ?

Comment: May be this helps  http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm